# How to extract custom file name using awk?

Tags: linux, awk

Is it possible to use FILENAME in awk so it doesn't write out the whole name of the file but just a part of it?

I would like to use:
`awk '{print FILENAME; nextfile}' filename_number_something.txt`

but in a way that it only returns the `number` part of the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow. So I believe you want to check multiple files of txt, if this is the case then you could try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{split(FILENAME, array,"_");print array[2]; nextfile}'  *.txt
```

So it will print the file name's second portion which is number, considering your all files have same pattern in their names.